# Connected components skeleton

Tags: c++, opencv, connected-components, opencv3.1

I'm working on features extraction from digits skeletons with OpenCV 3.1.0 on C++.
I'm looking for a method that give me the number of closed contours in an a skeleton image (for example 2 for 8, 1 for 0,6,9 and 0 for 1,2,3,4,5,7). I used the method `connectedComponents()` of OpenCV with 8-way connectivity but it didnt give me the hoped result. I get always 2 connected components in all images.
The problem  is that the inside and outside of the shape are 8-way connected so they are considered as one component.

This image will explain the main problem:

[image]

Is there a solution to get these features?

Comment: mmm... maybe try 4-way connectivity?

Comment: I tried it also. the skeleton was not considered as a single connected component.

Comment: Now I'm confused. What are you trying to detect as a connected component in the image above? The white contours (which are connected together), or the black discs inside the contours? If you invert the image and use 4-connection you should be able to get the two discs.